# Change colour of DataSeries in Excel 2003 VBA

Tags: vba, linechart, excel-2003

I'm having particular trouble changing the colour of a data series in Excel 2003 using VBA.

I've managed to change the colour of the line, but the colour is not correct. I'm very confused and I'm hoping someone could shed some light on what I'm doing wrong!

```
Dim strFundCode As String
strFundCode = Std_FleetUtils.GetVariableValueByName(avVariables, strVARIABLE_NAME_FUND)

Dim oChart As Chart
Set oChart = ActiveChart

Dim oSeries As Series
Set oSeries = oChart.SeriesCollection(1)

Select Case strFundCode

    Case strFUND_CODE_CAUTIOUS ' MPS Cautious

        oSeries.Border.Color = RGB(12, 86, 166)

    Case strFUND_CODE_BALANCED ' MPS Balanced

        oSeries.Border.Color = RGB(93, 19, 110)

    Case strFUND_CODE_BALANCED_INCOME ' MPS Balanced Income

        oSeries.Border.Color = RGB(70, 137, 176)

    Case strFUND_CODE_GROWTH ' MPS Growth

        oSeries.Border.Color = RGB(200, 139, 78)

    Case Else
        Err.Raise lGENERIC_ERROR, Description:="The fund code '" & strFundCode & "' is not recognized."

End Select
```

I've tried so many things (Interior.Color - threw up an error).

Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use:

```
oSeries.Format.Fill.BackColor = RGB(x,x,x)
```